# How to return the count of all repeatead strings in two lists?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, parsing

I have two big `.txt` files like this:

first file:

```
Hi how are you I'm pretty fine.
This is amazing oh yeah nice awesome.
...
I like stackoverflow.
```

second file:

```
hi 
this 
is 
amazing
i 
like 
it 
a 
lot 
nice
```

The first list_1 is a list of lists where each list is one line, the second is just a list of the second file. I read both files and put them in a list, like this:

```
list_1 = [[line.strip()] for line in open('path/first/file.txt')]


f_2 = open ('/path/file2.txt', 'r')
y = f.readlines()
print y

list_1 = [Hi how are you I'm pretty fine. This is amazing oh yeah nice awesome. ... I like stackoverflow.]

list_2 = [hi this is amazing. ... i like it a lot nice]
```

I would like to return in a tuple the line (e.g. list) and the count of words that appear in both (i.e. `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`). How can I return something like this:

```
[(1,count),(2,count),...,(n,count)]
```

Where `n` is the line number (list) and `count` is the number of times that a word from `list_2` appeared in `list_1` (all the words). thanks in advance guys!

Comment: `n` is the *first* line number? Or line number from `list_1`?

Comment: Yes is the first line number, thanks for the feedback! @Elizion

Comment: Is `n` the line number from where the word was found in file1 or file2?

Comment: You can turn a string of words into a list using the split member function:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
fh1 = open("/temp/temp1.txt","r")
fh2 = open("/temp/temp2.txt","r")

#you have to decide what a "word" is ...
def text2word(s):
  s = s.replace("\n","")
  s = s.replace(".","")
  return s.lower()

content1 = fh1.read()
counts1 = Counter(map(text2word, content1.split()))

counts2 = list()
for linenumber, word in enumerate(fh2):
  word = word.strip()
  print word
  ct = counts1[word]
  counts2.append((linenumber,ct))

print counts2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alan, I have a file with 100 lines, when I use this aproach this just returns the frecuency for 40 files. Any idea of why this happened?.

Comment: Did you mean 40 *lines*?   I put in a `print word` above; do you see all lines printed?  Note that I assumed one word per line in file 2, as in your original description.

Comment: Nice idea to use a Counter to speed up counting occurrences of words.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the second file contains one word per line, you can use the following code:

```
with open('/path/file1.txt') as f:
    all_words = f.read().split()
with open('/path/file1.txt') as f_2:
    words = f_2.read().split()
result = dict((n, all_words.count(w)) for (n, w) in enumerate(words))
print result
```

If you need the exact format you showed, then replace the last line with:

```
print result.items()
```

or the last two lines with:

```
result = [(n, all_words.count(w)) for (n, w) in enumerate(words)]
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `n` to represent the line of the second file

```
with open("file2.txt","r") as a, open("file1.txt", "r") as b:
words = dict((k.strip(),[i,0])for i, k in enumerate(a))      
b_words = [word.lower().split() for word in b]
for item in b_words:
    for word in item:
        if words.has_key(word):
            words[word][1] += 1          

for k,v in words.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

which outputs:

```
a [7, 0] 
like [5, 1]
this [1, 1]
is [2, 1]
it [6, 0]
i [4, 1]
amazing [3, 1]
hi [0, 1]
lot [8, 0]
nice [9, 1]
```

Now if you want to create a list of tuples depending on the values

```
f = [tuple(v) for k,v in words.iteritems()]
```

Comment: That's not what newWithPython asked for.

Comment: ok i added a line to convert the values into a list of tuples